# POST Request to Steam Leaderboard API always returns Forbidden

Tags: post, postman, steam, steam-web-api

I am trying to implement the Steam API for the leaderboards into my game. Before I wanted to make the code and everything I tried with Postman first. But as soon as I try to make a POST Request to ([documentation](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/ISteamLeaderboards))

https://partner.steam-api.com/ISteamLeaderboards/FindOrCreateLeaderboard/v2/?key=MYKEY&appid=MYAPPID&name=test

it returns me the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Forbidden</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Forbidden</h1>Access is denied. Retrying will not help. Please verify your
        <pre>key=</pre> parameter.
    </body>
</html>
```

I double checked the key and everything, they must be right since other Requests with the same App ID and Key work!
Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: ever figure it out?  I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: @tshoemake Sadly not, we ditched the idea in the end.